# Unresolved reference: getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent FacebookSDK

Tags: android, kotlin, facebook-sdk-4.0

Why does this error occur:"Unresolved reference: getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent"?
FacebookSDK latest version: implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'.
Manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

MainActivity:

```
FacebookSdk.setAutoInitEnabled(true)
        FacebookSdk.fullyInitialize()
        AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(applicationContext) { appLinkData ->
            val uri: Uri? =
                appLinkData?.targetUri ?: AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, intent)
            uri?.query?.let { preferences.edit().putString("PREFS_DEEPLINK", it).apply() }
            continuation.resume(uri?.query ?: "")
        }
```

Comment: I am using the com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:11.3.0

Comment: Did you have any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

That's settled. It was necessary to import correctly AppLinks: import bolts.AppLinks

Comment: error: package bolts does not exist
import bolts.AppLinks; in facebook sdk 11.3.0